# Circle progress bar on transition between two fragments

Tags: android, fragment, progress-bar, navigation-drawer, transition

I create a navigation drawer which contain fragments, each fragment take a several time to load.
So I want to implement a circle progress bar during the transition like gmail app below: [screenshot gmail app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX4uF.png)

**Main Activity.class**

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.profil) {

    }
    else if (id == R.id.accueil) {

        AccueilFragment fragment = new AccueilFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment );
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        floatingActionButton.show();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Accueil");


    } else if (id == R.id.categories) {
        CategoriesFragment fragment = new CategoriesFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment );
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        floatingActionButton.hide();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Categories");


    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

mProgressDialog.setMessage("Working ...");

private void doSomeWorkMethod() {

    mProgressDialog.show();

    doSomeWork . . .

    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

    Snackbar.make(v, "Work Complete.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
      .setAction("Action", null).show();
}
```

Comment: what's means the **v** in "Snackbar.make(v, "Work Complete.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();" cause it's red in my project

Comment: Snackbar is a pop up message like toast that appears at the bottom of the screen, v is view parameters passed, if you have problems implementing snack bar just implement a toast message instead.